# Is it worth to start learning rails 2 or should i wait until books on rails 3 are available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had always dreamed about learning rails and the ruby language, but there seems to be a big change comming with the new rails 3 release. So are there generally huge differences between 2 and 3? Should i probably start with rails 3 when books are available since this is the way i learn the best?

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, the best targets are Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2, especially if you need to start a new project or learning a new language.

If you are completely unfamiliar with both Ruby and Rails, then you first need to start with Ruby before working with Rails. For the time you will be more acquainted with Ruby, chances are most of the Rails 3 books will be released or in beta version.

In fact, there are several Rails 3 books almost finished. [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) and [The Rails 3 Way](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780132480345) are probably the most effective examples. By the way, you can already start learning Rails 3 right now. [Rails has great documentation](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/8/28/rails-has-great-documentation) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can start learning Rails 3 now, there are plenty of resources already on the net, e.g. here: http://railsnotes.com/rails-3/

Answer (score 0):

You could also pick up the beta version of Agile Web Development http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate the value of online documentation!